# Link URL base disappearing when sent in a mail via PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, email

Whenever I send a mail via PHP (content generated by jQuery, AJAX `POST` to PHP) the base of the URL gets missing when arriving at the destination.

So for instance, I send a mail with the following body:

```
Click <a href="http://www.example.com/?u=parameter&i=otherparameter">HERE</a> to go to the login page, etc, etc..

Use this link or copy it to your browser's address bar if the above doesn't work:
<a href="http://www.example.com/?u=parameter&i=otherparameter">http://www.example.com/?u=parameter&i=otherparameter</a>
```

Which looks like this:

*Click [HERE](http://www.example.com/?u=parameter&i=otherparameter) to go to the login page, etc, etc..*

*Use this link or copy it to your browser's address bar if the above doesn't work:
http://www.example.com/?u=parameter&i=otherparameter*

**But**, the receiver gets the *same* text, only without the links' base URL..

The link of `Click HERE` has the URL of only `/?u=parameter&i=otherparameter`, same goes for the other link, but the text of that link is fine. So it goes to the page where the mail is opened and appends the parameters there. It looks like this:

*Click [HERE](/?u=parameter&i=otherparameter) to go to the login page, etc, etc..*

*Use this link or copy it to your browser's address bar if the above doesn't work:
[http://www.example.com/?u=parameter&i=otherparameter](/?u=parameter&i=otherparameter)*

As you can see, the link will be directed to `stackoverflow.com`, instead of `example.com`. What is happening that either jQuery, AJAX or PHP strips my HTML, or is it a clientside problem?

(Tested in FF15/Chrome20/IE8, jQuery v1.7.2, PHP v5.3.5)

---

**EDIT**

This is how I send the mail with PHP:

```
$to      = $_POST['t'];
$subject = $_POST['s'];
$message = $_POST['m'];

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . 
           "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n" . 
           "From: <noreply@example.com>" . "\r\n" .
           "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: How do you know for sure what the body looks like before sending? Have you checked the value of `$message` before sending it to `mail()`? Have you used Chrome's or Firefox's dev tools to see exactly what is being POSTed to the server?

Comment: did you check the htaccess file ?? maybe it has been set on htaccess redirect file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a quick solution is to use the define the base url with the _SERVER global array read documentation at php manual for more.but the mail function should not fail...
Also where does AJAX come in in the posting of mails... that's php mail() function.Are you retrieving values from users or are the values dynamically retrieved using the   php or a database....

Comment: "define the base url with the _SERVER global array" - that did it for some reason, thanks!